# Como subtrair dois grandes vetores?

Tags: python-3.x, matemática

Eu quero calcular a diferença de vetor entre dois vetores de grande dimensão.
Eu sou capaz de subtrair uma lista de matrizes para uma matriz e colocá-lo ao poder de 2

```
(train["quest_emb"][0] - train["sent_emb"][0])**2
```

mas não generalizá-lo com uma coluna da tabela de dados da matriz para um quadro de dados da matriz:

```
train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"]
```

como ele trava meu computador.

#### Array analysis

Aqui está um exemplo de seu conteúdo.

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2]))
[[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2]))
[array([0.03037658, 0.04433101, 0.08135635, ..., 0.06764812, 0.04971079,
       0.02240689], dtype=float32), array([0.05260669, 0.04548098, 0.0382337 , ..., 0.04823414, 0.07656007,
       0.03501297], dtype=float32), array([0.0502927 , 0.04480611, 0.02038252, ..., 0.03942193, 0.03132772,
       0.04595207], dtype=float32), array([0.06769167, 0.03393815, 0.0625218 , ..., 0.05555448, 0.03059104,
       0.03422254], dtype=float32)]
```

Parece que há uma diferença no tamanho:

```
>>> print(len(train["quest_emb"][0]))
1
>>> print(len(train["sent_emb"][0]))
4
```

Aqui está o que o primeiro array se parece:

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03037658 0.04433101 0.08135635 ... 0.06764812 0.04971079 0.02240689]
```

O tamanho do vetor 'train [" quest_emb "]`e o mesmo do vetor 'train [" sent_emb "]`: 130318

Aqui estão os tipos das matrizes

```
>>> print(type(train["quest_emb"][2]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> print(type(train["sent_emb"][2]))
<class 'list'>
```

** Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa diferença computável para um computador com 8 G de RAM? Ou se não é uma maneira aproximada? **

#### Intento con theano

Tentei subtrair com Theano:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x - y
f = function([x, y], z)   
f(train["quest_emb"],train["sent_emb"])
```

Mas deu o error:

```
ValueError: Bad input argument with name "quest_emb" to theano function with name "<ipython-input-41-c53eb459cbc4>:6" at index 0 (0-based).
```

Comment: OI, você poderia converter o train["sent_emb"] para numpy.ndarray . Ficará mais rápido as interações e possivelmente resolverá seu problema.

Comment: @DaviMello Eu tentei e não funcionou, o problema é a eficiência em um número tão grande de linhas (130318). Eu tentei com menos da metade dos dados e ele calcula [sem sotcker os resultados até agora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323046/como-armazenar-um-resultado-em-um-dataframe). Mas não me pedem para fazer o trabalho no meio do caminho

Comment: Na variável  "sent_emb" tem 4 vetores. Você quer subtrair o "quest_emb", de cada um deles ?

Comment: isso e um problema universitário ou algo que possa postar no github. Que sem os dados, fica complicado poder ajudar realmente.